# How to manage list item lifecycles correctly in PySide2: RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (PySide2.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel) already deleted

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, pyside2

I am trying to port some code to PySide2 from PyQt5. I am having some object lifetime issues with TreeWidget. I am clearly not understanding something. When I try to access the data from the Model for a selected item in the tree I get a "Internal C++ object already deleted error" - but as far as I can see I have ensured that I have a current reference to the item data in scope.

The test case below demonstrates the issue. When the user selects the item from the Tree and then clicks the button the following error is reported:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test_case.py", line 33, in button_clicked
    self.tree.selectionModel().selection()[0]
RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (PySide2.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel) already deleted.
```

Clearly something is going out of scope but I can not see where.

How am I meant to prevent the items in the Model from being deleted?

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QAbstractItemView,
                               QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QGroupBox,
                               QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.tree = QTreeWidget(self)

        self.button = QPushButton(self, text="Run Tests")

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.button)

        self.frame = QGroupBox(self, title="Test &Run")
        self.frame.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)

        self.item = QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree)

        self.item.setText(0, "list item 1")

        self.show()

    def button_clicked(self):
        data = self.tree.selectionModel().model().data(
            self.tree.selectionModel().selection()[0]
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    app.mainWindow = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

Environment:
 Linux
 Python 3.5
 conda
 PySide 5.6.0a1
 qt 5.6.2

Update: I have checked that the same problem happens in the latest dev version of PySide2 (5.11a1) and raised a bug report [PYSIDE-639](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-639)

Comment: Your method of retrieving data looks really weird. To start with, the [`data()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) method takes a model-index as first argument, whereas you are passing in a `QItemSelectionRange`. But in any case, the correct way to do this is simply: `data = self.tree.selectedItems()[0].text(0)`.